# Is $z^{\frac{p}{q}}$, $\frac{p}{q}<1$ a holomorphic injection on $C\setminus[0,\infty)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $z^{\frac{p}{q}}$ $\frac{p}{q}<1$ a holomorphic injection on $C\setminus[0,\infty)$ (let the branch cut be on $[0,\infty)$)

I think so. Assume that $z_1,z_2$ map to the same element. We know they need to have the same modulus. So only the angle could be an issue. By definition we end up with $\frac{p}{q}(\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2))=2k\pi$ here comes the condition $\frac{p}{q}<1$ as unless $k=0$ the left side has absolute value less than $2\pi$. Thus $z_1=z_2$ IS this correct? If so, what are some additional conditions on the domain to make our function injective for some given $\frac{p}{q}$. For example when $p/q=2$ we just need the condition on the region that if $z$ is in it, $-z$ is not. So $z^2$ is injective on the upper half plane for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, a branch $f$ of $z^{p/q}$ with this branch cut maps $re^{i\theta}$ to $\alpha r^{p/q} e^{i \theta p/q}$ for $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$, where $\alpha$ is one of the possible values of $1^{p/q}$, i.e. $e^{2\pi i k p/q}$, $k = 0 \ldots q-1$.  If $0 < p/q < 1$, the map $\theta \to e^{i\theta p/q}$ is one-to-one on $(0,2\pi)$.  If $p/q > 1$, you would have to ensure, for any given $r$, the interval of possible values of $\theta$ (if it is an interval) has length less than $2\pi q/p$.